# Does Polyspace Code Prover have a mathematics library?

Tags: verification, formal-verification, formal-methods

MathWorks has a formal verification tool called Polyspace Code Prover. MathWorks' website claims that Polyspace uses formal mathematics to verify properties of programs. There is a free trial, but it isn't available to home users. Does anyone know if Polyspace has or uses a library of mathematical theories to formally verify properties of programs? If yes, in which language is this library written?

Answer (score 0):

Polyspace's libraries are all internal and automated, and using them requires you to run your code analysis with Polyspace from its user interface, or command-line interface.

As evidenced by the page for the MathWorks' [DO-178 Qualification Kit](https://www.mathworks.com/products/do-178.html), Polyspace is a Formal Methods tool and can be qualified under DO-333 (the Formal Methods supplement).  There is a similar capability for the MathWorks' [IEC Certification Kit](https://www.mathworks.com/products/iec-61508.html).